# Does SonarQube need extra config/plugins to understand jacoco reports

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I am using SonarQube `Version 6.7.3 (build 38370)` and my coverage report is not working (always showing 0%). I verified that after running `./mvnw clean verify install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=...` the `jacoco.xml` file is created under the default expected location for the `sonar-maven-plugin`. The report is correctly showing `66%` code coverage.

I see that my SonarQube's helm chart was installed with

```
plugins:
  install:
    - "https://github.com/stevespringett/dependency-check-sonar-plugin/releases/download/1.1.1/sonar-dependency-check-plugin-1.1.1.jar"
```

which makes me think that I need to install something extra for jacoco to work. Also, in [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JaCoCo+Plugin) page it is said that

> This plugin (provided by default with SonarQube 7.4+) allows you to load the JaCoCo data from its XML format for all the languages for which you can generate a JaCoCo report.

and my version is 6.7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - import of JaCoCo XML report requires a [SonarQube JaCoCo Plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-jacoco).

[Page about plugin that you cite](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JaCoCo+Plugin) contains not only

> provided by default with SonarQube 7.4+

but also

> JaCoCo 1.0.2 – Jun 28, 2019 – **SonarQube 6.7+** (Compatible with LTS)

meaning that plugin is compatible with SonarQube versions starting from `6.7` and pre-installed starting from version `7.4`.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/6.7/InstallingaPlugin.html describes how to install plugins:

[image: how to install plugin]